# How can I see from Windows which Thunderbolt version (3 or 4) my Windows 10 laptop has?

Tags: windows-10, thunderbolt

My Windows 10 laptop has a Thunderbolt port.  How can I see from Windows which Thunderbolt  version (3 or 4) my Windows 10 laptop has? I'd prefer not to manually dig into the laptop user manual.

Thunderbolt  versions 3 and 4 both use a USB-C connector:

[image]

(Image author: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Amin ; licensed under the Creative Commons Attribution-Share Alike 4.0 International)

I don't see the Thunderbolt version in the Device Manager:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

> How can I see from Windows which Thunderbolt version (3 or 4) my Windows 10 laptop has?

The simplest way, base it on which processor you have; only 11th generation Intel processors and newer come with TB4 support.  Since you are running Windows 10, one can rule out the fact, that you are running anything newer than the 11th generation since all 12th generation processor products were only sold with Windows 11.

At the end of the day, you have to look to the specifications of your laptop to determine if it’s TB3 or TB4, or you can immediately determine it’s NOT TB4 by the sheer fact you **don’t** have an 11th generation or newer processor.

If you have the Intel Thunderbolt drivers installed, there is a Thunderbolt application. That application will indicate which ports support TB4 on applicable hardware.

[image]

Comment: "You wouldn’t and that’s an intentional design decision." Why intentional?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt - Intel intentionally made the decision not to indicate the version of TB the controller supports, in the description of the TB controller, this is evident by the fact they didn’t do it